# Grunt isn't updating scripts when saving changes

Tags: javascript, wordpress, node.js, gruntjs

I'm totally new to `Grunt`, I'm using the `Roots` `Wordpress` starter theme which has an included `Gruntfile.js` like so:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        'assets/js/*.js',
        '!assets/js/scripts.min.js'
      ]
    },
    less: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'assets/css/main.min.css': [
            'assets/less/app.less'
          ]
        },
        options: {
          compress: true,
          // LESS source map
          // To enable, set sourceMap to true and update sourceMapRootpath based on your install
          sourceMap: false,
          sourceMapFilename: 'assets/css/main.min.css.map',
          sourceMapRootpath: '/app/themes/roots/'
        }
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'assets/js/scripts.min.js': [
            'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/transition.js',
            'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/alert.js',
            'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/button.js',
            'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/carousel.js',
            'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/collapse.js',
            'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/dropdown.js',
            'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/modal.js',
            'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/tooltip.js',
            'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/popover.js',
            'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/scrollspy.js',
            'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/tab.js',
            'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/affix.js',
            'assets/js/plugins/*.js',
            'assets/js/_*.js'
          ]
        },
        options: {
          // JS source map: to enable, uncomment the lines below and update sourceMappingURL based on your install
          // sourceMap: 'assets/js/scripts.min.js.map',
          // sourceMappingURL: '/app/themes/roots/assets/js/scripts.min.js.map'
        }
      }
    },
    version: {
      options: {
        file: 'lib/scripts.php',
        css: 'assets/css/main.min.css',
        cssHandle: 'roots_main',
        js: 'assets/js/scripts.min.js',
        jsHandle: 'roots_scripts'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      less: {
        files: [
          'assets/less/*.less',
          'assets/less/bootstrap/*.less'
        ],
        tasks: ['less', 'version']
      },
      js: {
        files: [
          '<%= jshint.all %>'
        ],
        tasks: ['jshint', 'uglify', 'version']
      },
      livereload: {
        // Browser live reloading
        // https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#live-reloading
        options: {
          livereload: false
        },
        files: [
          'assets/css/main.min.css',
          'assets/js/scripts.min.js',
          'templates/*.php',
          '*.php'
        ]
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dist: [
        'assets/css/main.min.css',
        'assets/js/scripts.min.js'
      ]
    }
  });

  // Load tasks
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-wp-version');

  // Register tasks
  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'clean',
    'less',
    'uglify',
    'version'
  ]);
  grunt.registerTask('dev', [
    'watch'
  ]);

};
```

From what I can see, `Grunt`should be watching for changes to anything in my `/assets/js/*` folder.

However, when I:

- Add a new script, like `/assets/js/plugins/jquery-thing.js`
- Update a script, like `/assets/js/_main.js`

It doesn't properly update nor compile the scripts into `scripts.min.js`. )I think this is the `uglify` operation, for what it's worth).

Any idea what's going wrong here? I'm updating these files but Wordpress is just pulling in very old script versions. I've tried replacing the `gruntfile` with a fresh one from the `Roots` github page, but to no avail.

EDIT: I have `grunt watch` running in console, just to state the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your watch js is watching files described in jshint.all

But the jshint.all don't include the files in the plugin folder. Try something like this:

```
jshint: {
  options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
  },
  all: [
    'Gruntfile.js',
    'assets/js/**/*.js',
    '!assets/js/scripts.min.js'
  ]
},
```

Or you can put the js files you want to watch directly in the watch options, like this:

```
watch: {
  less: {
    files: [
      'assets/less/*.less',
      'assets/less/bootstrap/*.less'
    ],
    tasks: ['less', 'version']
  },
  js: {
    files: [
      'assets/js/**/*.js'
    ],
    tasks: ['jshint', 'uglify', 'version']
  },
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't actually want jshint to run at all, as it keeps giving me errors in plugins like missing semicolons and whatnot which don't affect the code's ability to run but are a total bitch to fix up (especially with minified files). Is there a way around this?